# Unable to get variable outside subscribe in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

Well, maybe my issue sounds similar to the few questions here about Angular2-EventEmitter-Subject-Observable-Subscribe-stuff... but it's quite different.

**My goal** (in short):

Be able to go from route *ItemsList* to route *AddNewItem* and then push on the custom 'back' button and find myself in *ItemsList* WITH ALL SETTINGS THAT I HAD HERE. For a example - search params. So... the only way (afaik) in Angular2+ to store that params between non-related components is to use shared service. So... My code:

**ItemsList ts\html** (very briefly):

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  public addItem(allSettings: ISettingsTable) {
   this._shService.returnToList = true;
   this._shService.allCurrentSettings = allSettings;
   this._router.navigate(['someRoute', 'add']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._settings = {
      search: /* .. */,
      /* .. */
    }

    this._shService.getSettings().subscribe((settings: ISettingsTable) => { 
      this._settings = settings;
    }
  }
}

<button (click)='addItem(_settings)'>
  <mat-icon svgIcon='add'></mat-icon>
</button>
```

**Service** (in short):

```
export class SettingsService {
  private _returnToList: boolean;
  private _settingsChanged$: Subject<ISettingsTable> = new Subject();

  public emitSettings(val: ISettingsTable) {
    this._settingsChanged$.next(val);
  }
  public getSettings(): Subject<ISettingsTable> {
    return this._settingsChanged$;
  }
}
```

**AddEditItems ts\html** (very briefly as well):

```
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
  public back(par: ISettingsTable): void {
    if (this.returnToList) {
      this._router.navigate(['someRoute', 'list']).then(() => {
        this._shService.emitSettings(par);
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this._shService.returnToList) {
      this.returnToList = true;
      this._p = this._testS.allCurrentSettings;
    }
  }
}

<button mat-raised-button (click)='back(_p)'>Go back</button>
```

**So!** When I go to the *Add* route I store the current params in service. Fine. Then on the *Add* route I get them from service. Fine. Then when I wanna go back I pass that params to the emit method of Subject\Event Emitter... Fine! But on the **List** route `this._settings` exists only INSIDE subscribe... It's undefined outside. Yeah, I know about  asynchronous behavior and stuff... But how to resolve my issue properly??? Anyone! Please. Hope I made myself clear.

**EDIT...**

Obviously I always on all routes have some settings. The issue is I dunno how to code *If I've got some settings from observable - use them, if not - use default this._settings* ...

Comment: What do you mean `exists only inside`? `this._settings = settings;` is setting the property within your subscribe. Are you trying to use the property before the subscribe finishes?

Comment: @LLai of course, as you can see this._settings always is 'working'. It has some params always. But when I go back I wanna apply certain params - the one I get from subscribe. I mean, I do not trying to use before, but it happens because I always has 'default' settings...

Comment: I think you want a BehaviorSubject (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) instead of your Subject. The behavior subject will return the last or initial values when you subscribe to it. Whereas with the subject, you will only get values that are emitted after you subscribe

Comment: @LLai thanks, I'll try...

Comment: this is not a unique or uncommon issue, the problem is that you're subscribing after the event has occurred, @LLai is correct that you need a behavior subject instead of a subject if you're trying to store state in a subject.  A behaviorsubject is different than a subject in that in broadcasts it's current value to all new subscribers on subscription, while normal subjects only broadcast to current subscribers when an event occurs

Comment: @bryan60 I've just updated my question... to specificate my problem :) Anyway thanks, I'm trying to implement BehaviorSubject and now I'm gettin dozen errors...

Comment: then you should post that code.  The problem here IS definitely, 100%, no doubt, what me and the other poster stated.

Comment: It is important to note that a BehaviorSubject requires an initial value. This is so subscribers receive a value when they subscribe (even if nothing has manually sent to the Subject)